# PHP: Signup > USERNAME with only Greek Characters and only one white space

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I would like my user to only be able to write Greek characters with only one white space between their first and last name. How do I change this PHP code to do that?

```
!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$/", $newusername)
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote it. If it solved your problem, please mark it accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [the `/u` modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to make the expression Unicode-aware, and I prefer using hex codes when specifying these sorts of things – it can be hard to tell apart an alpha (Α) from an ay (A).

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_and_Coptic), the Unicode block "Greek and Coptic" uses codes from 0x370 to 0x3ff:

```
function checkGreek($newusername) {
    if (preg_match("/^[\x{370}-\x{3FF} ]{1,50}$/u", $newusername)) {
        echo "It's Greek to me";
    } else {
        echo "Non-Greek in there";
    }
}
checkGreek("ΑΒ ΓΔ");
checkGreek("ΑΒ ΓΔ 123");
checkGreek("AB CD");
```

Comment: miken32, your advice is very helpful. I will follow it.